# Using a PHP script as a post-commit hook, to trigger a bash script, to do a git-pull?

Tags: php, git, bash, github, ssh-keys

Here's the bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "$NODE_ENV"
(
echo $USER;
echo $PATH;
cd /opt/chat-staging/;
git pull;
NODE_ENV=staging;
echo "Set NODE_ENV to $NODE_ENV";
node leaderboard.js & node app.js;
echo "Started leaderboard.js";
echo "Started app.js";
)
echo "NODE_ENV is now $NODE_ENV"
```

Here's the PHP script:

```
<?php

exec('/bin/bash /opt/chat-staging/start_app.sh 2>&1', &$output, &$return_var);
print_r($output);
print $return_var;

?>
```

I have it set up as a github post-commit hook, but this is the output:

> Array ( [0] => [1] => www-data [2] => /usr/bin [3] =>
>   /usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-setup: 90: sed: not found [4] => basename:
>   write error: Broken pipe [5] => /usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-setup: 212:
>   uname: not found [6] => Host key verification failed. [7] => fatal:
>   The remote end hung up unexpectedly [8] => Set NODE_ENV to staging [9]
>   => /opt/chat-staging/start_app.sh: line 11: node: command not found [10] => /opt/chat-staging/start_app.sh: line 11: node: command not
>   found [11] => Started leaderboard.js [12] => Started app.js [13] =>
>   NODE_ENV is now ) 0

/opt/chat-staging/ is owned by the "www-pub";  in /etc/groups, I have "www-pub:x:1000:www-data,root".

So why is this not working?  I even have an RSA key in /var/www/.ssh/id_rsa and the public key added as a GitHub deploy key.

**EDIT, ADDENDUM**

I added a git remote-v; to the script, right before "git pull".

```
root@li70-243:/opt/chat-staging# su - www-data
$ bash /opt/chat-staging/start_app.sh
origin  git@github.com:zackster/CompassionPit--Node-.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:zackster/CompassionPit--Node-.git (push)
Already up-to-date.
```

Whereas I still see PHP output like...

> Array ( [0] => origin git@github.com:zackster/CompassionPit--Node-.git
>   (fetch) [1] => origin git@github.com:zackster/CompassionPit--Node-.git
>   (push) [2] => master [3] => * reputation [4] =>
>   /usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-setup: 90: sed: not found [5] => basename:
>   write error: Broken pipe [6] => /usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-setup: 212:
>   uname: not found [7] => /usr/lib/git-core/git-pull: 244: sed: not
>   found [8] => Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref
>   'reputation' [9] => from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.

Comment: Why do you want to use a PHP script??

Comment: /var/www isn't the home directory of www-pub nor www-data, they don't have any basically.

Comment: Debug bash-script by hand from console - you have **a lot of errors** during execution

Comment: @knittl, I use a PHP script because it's so easy.  Fewest keystrokes for me.

Comment: @knittl if you can recommend a better, faster, smarter, more secure solution - I will implement *that* instead! I am always eager to learn

Comment: @greut I have no idea why I added that, then.  I think I saw mention of /var/www in the PHP script output at some point, so I added that.  My inkling was if that *were* the home directory, then I could bolt the ssh key there..

Comment: I don't see why you would have the PHP script call the bash script, instead of calling the bash script directly …?

Comment: @knittl Can I do that from nginx?

Comment: @LazyBadger Good thinking, I just did 'su www-data' and am trying to debug it now.  But I ran into an issue with my PS1 prompt, and now I'm problem-solving in bash!

Comment: @ZacharyBurt: I thought this was about git hooks? They execute shell scripts.

Comment: @LazyBadger updated the OP with what I learned from running bash script as www-data user..

Comment: @knittl No clue what the best practice is.  I thought that setting up a GitHub post receive hook would be good, but if I can do it locally I suppose that would be better.. any way to automatically 'git pull' when a 'git push' is done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your PHP script seems to work fine. What's not "working fine" is the `exec()`. You expect the `PATH` environment variable to be set to whatever your regular shell user has set. It is not. You need to set the environment for the bash script (and the tools therein) to work.

do `echo $PATH` in *your* shell and add that to your exec:

```
exec('export PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/some/other/paths && /bin/bash /opt/chat-staging/start_app.sh 2>&1', &$output, &$return_var);
```

and try your script again. You could also move that PATH to your shell script. You could even copy *your* .bashrc (or .bash_profile or whatever) and load that with `source …/.bashrc`.

instead of `exec()` you could also look into [proc_open()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) with which you have much more control over the process to execute.

---

github explains how to hook into post receive events: http://help.github.com/post-receive-hooks/

Comment: exec('export PATH = /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games && /bin/bash /opt/chat-staging/start_app.sh 2>&1', &$output, &$return_var); --- now outputs Array ( ) 2

Comment: yes, I added spaces where there shouldn't be any. `export PATH=/usr/…` instead of `export PATH = /usr/`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this was a very frustrating problem!